# of ios, Customize a tableView or a tableView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, datasource, customization

I'm developing on IOS.

My current viewController has to display a tableView on the screen, as well as a a update button.

When user tapped this button, current tableView should be moved to **leave** the screen to the left and released,

at the same time, a new tableView should be allocced and moved **in** the screen from the right with some new data.

Note that the 2 table holds **diffirent** data, so I'm thinking how to implement this.

Now I have 2 ideas:

**1st**. let my current viewController be the delegate and dataSource of these tables, and the different would be embodied in delegate and dataSource method such as:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (_aNewTableView) return 0;
    else  return [sections count];
}
```

but question is, these flag parameters belongs to current ViewController and be shared by both old and new tables,

so when I alloc a new tableView preparing to move in the screen,

would it affect the old table or be affected by the old one since then share some same flag parameters?

**2nd**. customize a tableView, and give them some private methods to configure their data or look separatly,

but I need to overwrite those delegate and dataSource methods.

Further more, the custom tableView's delegate and dataSource should still be a view Controller,

which means I have to creat a new controller specially for the customized tableView, it seems to make problem more complicated.

And I'm not sure whether I know how to overwrite the tableViewDelegate and tableViewDataSource.

So what should I do to realize this function?

Thanks a lot for concerning and answering!

Comment: If you are asking about iPhone, please add a tag for that. And/or whatever programming language you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for remind! I've already updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this.

I choosed the 1st method, that is, directly creat a tableView after take care with the current tableView and all the flags the new table need.

then use uianimation to move the 2 tables to where they should be, then release the leaved table and retain the new one.

that's all.